# Sage CRM - Error when clicking to create a new appoinment

Tags: sage-crm

I was deleting fields to the screen (Fields i do not want right now) but after deleting them the screen to create a new appointment stopped working.

THere is some field that have to be in that screen no matter what?

I the screen i modified was CommunicationDetailBox

```
sep. 13 2016 16:09:50.492   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   183 
sep. 13 2016 16:09:50.565   4248    348 3   CoeWareBase,Time    16
sep. 13 2016 16:09:51.009   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   183 515
sep. 13 2016 16:09:51.353   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1696    
sep. 13 2016 16:09:51.358   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1696    0
sep. 13 2016 16:09:52.910   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   362 
sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.187   4248    348 3   CoeWareBase,Time    32
sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.264   4248    348 1   UserActionException,ErrMsg  Access violation at address 1A687D6E in module 'eware.dll'. Write of address 00000019
sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.264   4248    348 1    : EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 1A687D6E in module 'eware.dll'. Write of address 00000019<br>
sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.309   4248    348 1   Creating stack-trace ID:4187146410. Error message is "Access violation at address 1A687D6E in module 'eware.dll'. Write of address 00000019"
sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.310   4248    348 1   

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Address |Module      |Unit               |Class                 |Procedure/Method       |Line     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1A687D6E|eware.dll   |WsCommunication.pas|TWebCommunication     |GetEditInfoFromContent |1180[93] |
|1A687910|eware.dll   |WsCommunication.pas|TWebCommunication     |GetEditInfoFromContent |1087[0]  |
|1A695A66|eware.dll   |WsCommunication.pas|TWebNewCommunication  |BuildScreen            |3488[132]|
|1A695344|eware.dll   |WsCommunication.pas|TWebNewCommunication  |BuildScreen            |3356[0]  |
|1A697700|eware.dll   |WsCommunication.pas|TWebNewCommunication  |BuildContents          |3887[176]|
|1A7F25BD|eware.dll   |WebPage.pas        |TWebPage              |GetHtml                |455[11]  |
|1A2E846B|eware.dll   |WebFrameSet.pas    |TWebFrameSet          |GetHtml                |685[221] |
|1A2E79EC|eware.dll   |WebFrameSet.pas    |TWebFrameSet          |GetHtml                |464[0]   |
|1A2E5D25|eware.dll   |WebFrameSet.pas    |TWebFrameSet          |GetHtml                |110[4]   |
|1A8917D0|eware.dll   |Dispatch.pas       |TDispatcher           |Action                 |3763[918]|
|1A88E8A4|eware.dll   |Dispatch.pas       |TDispatcher           |Action                 |2845[0]  |
|1A918F6F|eware.dll   |ISAPIDispatch.pas  |TISAPIEntry           |ISAPIEntryAction       |334[25]  |
|1A8D59C3|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TWebActionItem        |GetMask                |1244[19] |
|1A8D55F3|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TWebActionItem        |DispatchAction         |1108[18] |
|1A8D5500|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TWebActionItem        |DispatchAction         |1090[0]  |
|1A8D623F|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TCustomWebDispatcher  |DispatchAction         |1488[15] |
|1A8D61B8|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TCustomWebDispatcher  |DispatchAction         |1473[0]  |
|1A8D647E|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TCustomWebDispatcher  |HandleRequest          |1543[3]  |
|1A8D7E0D|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TDefaultWebAppServices|InvokeDispatcher       |2287[3]  |
|1A8D7DD0|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TDefaultWebAppServices|InvokeDispatcher       |2284[0]  |
|1A8D7DB0|eware.dll   |HTTPApp.pas        |TDefaultWebAppServices|HandleRequest          |2268[1]  |
|1A14EACD|eware.dll   |WebReq.pas         |TWebRequestHandler    |HandleRequest          |368[25]  |
|1A14E99C|eware.dll   |WebReq.pas         |TWebRequestHandler    |HandleRequest          |343[0]   |
|1A14F9F2|eware.dll   |ISAPIApp.pas       |TISAPIApplication     |HttpExtensionProc      |100[6]   |
|1A14F998|eware.dll   |ISAPIApp.pas       |TISAPIApplication     |HttpExtensionProc      |94[0]    |
|1A14FAF5|eware.dll   |ISAPIApp.pas       |                      |HttpExtensionProc      |147[10]  |
|7708039B|ntdll.dll   |                   |                      |RtlReleaseSRWLockShared|         |
|7707F4D0|ntdll.dll   |                   |                      |RtlLeaveCriticalSection|         |
|7707FD7D|ntdll.dll   |                   |                      |RtlAllocateHeap        |         |
|76499B96|msvcrt.dll  |                   |                      |malloc                 |         |
|76948541|KERNEL32.DLL|                   |                      |BaseThreadInitThunk    |         |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sep. 13 2016 16:09:53.310   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   362 405
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.136   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   106 
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.147   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   106 16
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.177   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1650    
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.268   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Campaign Launch Failure Notice,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10148 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.281   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Campaign Over Budget,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10149 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.297   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Campaign Close To Budget,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10150 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.309   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Email Reminder,DontDoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 65 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.312   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Communication Reminder,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 117 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.333   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Mailchimp list upload message,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10153 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.339   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Daily Quota Remaining,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10169 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.376   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Quarterly Quota Remaining First Month,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10170 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.389   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Quarterly Quota Remaining Second Month,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10171 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.401   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Quarterly Quota Remaining Third Month,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10172 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.412   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Pipeline Update,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10173 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.443   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Unassigned Lead,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10164 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.505   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Backup Failure Notice,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10151 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.518   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Backup Completed Notice,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10152 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.529   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Unassigned Opportunity,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10165 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.581   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,High Value Opportunity Created,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10166 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.668   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,HighValue Opportunity Won,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10167 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.753   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Lost Opportunities,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10162 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.864   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Opportunity Close Date Approaching,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10163 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.923   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Quote Discount Exceeded,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10168 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:19.999   4248    348 5   RunEscalations,EWAREDLL,Quote Expiry,DoRule,select * from vWorkflowActions where WkRl_RuleId = 10123 AND  Wkac_action = N'Notify'
sep. 13 2016 16:13:20.401   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1650    1217
sep. 13 2016 16:13:22.658   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1650    
sep. 13 2016 16:13:23.032   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1650    374
sep. 13 2016 16:13:31.564   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   808 
sep. 13 2016 16:13:32.221   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   808 656
sep. 13 2016 16:13:32.584   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1696    
sep. 13 2016 16:13:32.590   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1696    0
sep. 13 2016 16:13:34.292   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   810 
sep. 13 2016 16:13:34.639   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   810 344
sep. 13 2016 16:14:29.599   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   183 
sep. 13 2016 16:14:29.640   4248    348 3   CoeWareBase,Time    0
sep. 13 2016 16:14:29.895   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   183 296
sep. 13 2016 16:14:30.348   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1696    
sep. 13 2016 16:14:30.354   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1696    0
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.831   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   362 
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.896   4248    348 3   CoeWareBase,Time    16
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.932   4248    348 1   UserActionException,ErrMsg  Access violation at address 1A687D6E in module 'eware.dll'. Write of address 00000019
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.932   4248    348 1    : EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 1A687D6E in module 'eware.dll'. Write of address 00000019<br>
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.963   4248    348 1   Already logged ID: 4187146410
sep. 13 2016 16:14:31.964   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   362 124
sep. 13 2016 16:14:36.286   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   106 
sep. 13 2016 16:14:36.306   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   106 31
sep. 13 2016 16:14:36.335   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   523 
sep. 13 2016 16:14:36.692   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   523 359
sep. 13 2016 16:14:38.099   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1650    
sep. 13 2016 16:14:38.526   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1650    421
sep. 13 2016 16:14:39.490   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1651    
sep. 13 2016 16:14:39.859   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1651    375
sep. 13 2016 16:14:39.865   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1586    
sep. 13 2016 16:14:40.242   4248    348 4   EndUserAction,User,Action,Time  1   1586    374
sep. 13 2016 16:14:42.170   4248    348 4   StartUserAction,User,Action 1   1282
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that the Comm_Organizar HAVE to be in the screen CustomCommunicationDetailBox no matter what